# Why don’t numbers with a difference of 2 have any common factors beside 1 and possibly 2?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example, if x is odd, that means x-1 and x+1 are both even.  And from what I’ve seen, because x+1 and x-1 have a difference of 2, they have no other common factors beside 1 and because they are both even, 2.  If x is even, then x+1 and x-1 are both odd and therefore have only 1 as a common factor.

My questions are:

1. Is this true in all cases?
2. If so, why is this true?

Comment: Try it.  If  $a|m$ and $a|(m+2)$ Then $\frac ma$ is an integer and $\frac {m+2}a = \frac ma +\frac 2a$ is an integer. Subtracting those we get $\frac 2a$ is an integer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $x,y$ are numbers with $d$ as common factor, then $|x-y|$ is also a multiple of $d$. Hence either $x=y$ or $|x-y|\ge d$. Therefore, numbers with $|x-y|=2$ cannot have a common factor $d$ that is $>2$. Two even such numbers certainly have *at least* and hence exactly $2$ as common factor. Two odd numbers cannot have an even common factor, hence $1$.

Comment: At looks as if our answers displeased someone.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos what do you mean?

Comment: @LesgoMyBoi Someone downvoted both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true in all cases. **Hint:** if $m$ is a common factor of $a$ and $b$, then $m$ divides $a-b$.